# Using a PHP function in conjunction with a regular expression match

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to come up with a way to find all RegEx matches in a string, then run all of those matches through a function that I've written, but I'm having no luck.

Specifically, I'm trying to find all email addresses in a string and then use a function to convert those addresses into useful mailto links that hide the addresses from spam bots.

So I start with plain old RegEx to turn the addresses into mailto links, just so I know that the matches are working.

```
$pattern = '#([0-9a-z]([-_.]?[0-9a-z])*@[0-9a-z]([-.]?[0-9a-z])*\\.[a-wyz][a-z](fo|g|l|m|mes|o|op|pa|ro|seum|t|u|v|z)?)#i';
$replacement = "<a href='mailto:\\1'>\\1</a>";
$description = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $description);
```

Works great. So far, so good. But when I try to use my function to manipulate the address string, email addresses are no longer matched.

```
$pattern = '#([0-9a-z]([-_.]?[0-9a-z])*@[0-9a-z]([-.]?[0-9a-z])*\\.[a-wyz][a-z](fo|g|l|m|mes|o|op|pa|ro|seum|t|u|v|z)?)#i';
$replacement = myFunction('\\1');
$description = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $description);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$description = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'myFunction', $description);
```

Check [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) on manual to understand how it works.

Your `myFunction()` function should be coded like that:

```
function myFunction($matches)
{
    return sprintf('<a href="mailto:%s">%s</a>', $matches[1], $matches[1]);
}
```

Using `preg_replace_callback()` with a closure (PHP 5.3+):

```
$description = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) {
    return myFunction($matches[1]);
}, $description);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if this solution will work in my situation. First, myFunction is used across many pages (it's in an include file included in all of my pages), so I can't customize it for this specific circumstance. Second, myFunction actually takes three arguments (I only showed one argument in the code I posted here for the sake of readability). So would preg_replace_callback still be the solution here?

Comment: `preg_replace_callback()` pass matches to the callback function as argument. You might want to create a new callback function that uses your `myFunction()`, or even better, use a closure as callback (PHP 5.3+). I'll update my answer with a closure example. :)